DD a remote disk from windows
I want to using dd command to write a remote disk from my windows. I have download dd.exe already. My command is as below:
dd if=D:\tmp\a.wic | ssh root@192.168.1.5 'dd of=/dev/mmcblk0'
But I got response.
sh: dd of=/dev/mmcblk0: No such file or directory
It looks like windows doesn't recognize /dev/mmcblk0.
Is there anyone know how to fix this?
Eric

What's up with ssh? Which computer is 192.168.1.5? Does it have a mmcblk0 device?

My EVM board is Linux based, It's 192.168.1.5. EMMC device inside is /dev/mmcblk0. My PC is windows.

Read the error message closely. File "dd of=/dev/mmcblk0" not found. You don't want to quote the argument to ssh. ssh root@192.168.1.5 dd of=/dev/mmcblk0 (3 arguments to ssh: root@192.168.1.5, dd, of=/dev/mmcblk0). Also, dd if=/... can be replaced with cat /...
